# How to solve Uncaught (in promise), Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null on Webcam Media​Devices

Tags: javascript, webcam, mediadevices

I'm working on '`mediaDevices`' to try to capture webcam using javascript. Below is my code.

```
'use strict';

const video = document.getElementById('video');
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const snap = document.getElementById("snap");
const errorMsgElement = document.querySelector('span#errorMsg');

const constraints = {
  audio: true,
  video: {
    width: 1280, height: 720
  }
};
// Access webcam
async function init() {
  try {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
    handleSuccess(stream);
  } catch (e) {
    //console.error('navigator.getUserMedia error:', e);
    errorMsgElement.innerHTML = e.toString();
  }
}

// Success
function handleSuccess(stream) {
  //console.log('getUserMedia() got stream:', stream);
  window.stream = stream;
  video.srcObject = stream;
}

// Load init
init();
```

I already enable webcam setting in google chrome but I have '`Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`' instead. I'm new in javascript, Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: It looks like `errorMsgElement` is `null`. That is probably because you're setting this variable before the DOM is ready or there isn't any `span#errorMsg` element.

Comment: Dear Titus, Appreciated much for more details, thanks.

Comment: I was addressing the error message not the problem with the `mediaDevices` API. The error message says that `errorMsgElement` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Two things are probably incorrect here:

1. You've accidentally mis-spelt the id tag. (errorMsg)
2. You've tried selecting the element before it was loaded in the DOM.

Try the following:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   // your code here
});
```